# Connecting Full Calendar (via Google) to React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, react-props

I am trying to implement Full Calendar with event sourcing from a Google calendar. The calendar is rendering, my API key and calendar ID are console logging correctly from my .env, but I'm getting an error

`CalendarDataManager.ts:667 Unknown option 'googleCalendarApiKey'`

It sounds like it's not recognizing my prop for the API key, but according to the docs and other tutorials this looks correct. Any thoughts?

```
import "./eventcalendar.css";

// full calendar node package
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react"; // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid"; // a plugin!
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; // allows click events
import googleCalendarPlugin from "@fullcalendar/google-calendar";

function EventCalendar() {
  const googleCalendarURL = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;
  // const myGoogleCalendarID = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ID;
  const myGoogleCalendarID = "samplestring@gmail.com";

  // When a date grid is clicked, this function will invoke
  const handleDateClick = (dateClickInfo) => {
    console.log(dateClickInfo.dateStr);
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar-container ">
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        dateClick={handleDateClick}
        googleCalendarApiKey={googleCalendarURL}
        events={[{ googleCalendarId: myGoogleCalendarID }]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default EventCalendar;
```

Comment: Agreed this looks correct. Not sure what we can do about it here. Have you raised a bug with fullCalendar? https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: Turns out I've been staring at it too long! I took a break to do something else and realized I had run the `npm i @fullcalendar/google-calendar` into the wrong package.json. Still can't get my events to pull, but redoing all of the installs together in the right file fixed the errors lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find this error anywhere else, so here's what worked for me:

Double check your package.json to make sure all of the @full-calendar packages you're using are there. Mine were installed into two separate areas of my app which caused the error.